# RDP: Remote app does not encapsulate traffic when connecting via remote desktop gateway server

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services, windows-terminal-services, remoteapp

I have a remote desktop app that was published from a third-party corporation to one of my clients. The remote desktop app connects to a Remote Desktop Gateway Server (RDGW), which forwards the request to a Remote Desktop-serverfarm, where the least used server responds to the request and opens the app. This works perfectly fine for most scenarios.

Today I encountered a situation (let's say the App was published for a new customer), where the RemoteApp would ask the user for his credentials (domain\username and password), right after authenticating the user and accepting the certificate for the RDS farm, mstsc.exe will stop working, being totally unresponsive to cancel or close buttons, and has to be terminated via taskmanager.

While troubleshooting this issue I discovered a difference in the way the RemoteApp connects with the RemoteDesktop Gateway server.
In all my positive test scenarios the traffic was completely encapsulated in HTTPS between my MSTSC and the Remote Desktop Server Gateway like this: [image: Sucessfull Remote App connection in MS Netmon]

Logging the traffic for the exact same procedure on one of the failing mstsc's gave me this:
[image: Failing Remote App connection in MS Netmon]

The first conversation (as its called in NetMon) is the HTTPS connection to the RemoteDesktop Gateway server (HTTPS, Port 443), **followed by a seperate RDP connection**, that tries to connect to the RD server itself via its private IP address (I just blanked it in the picture for privacy and security reasons). The second connection eventually fails, because the RD server is not in the same location / subnet, so the private adress is not reachable for the mstsc.

At first I suspected the clients firewall, since it inspects HTTPS traffic, replacing certificates, so it could break a successfull HTTPS connection to the RDGW server. After disabling all webfilter functions on the firewall, the issue still persists. I also tried routing the traffic through a OpenVPN tunnel so it bypasses the firewall completely, sadly without success either.

What could force mstsc not to encapsulate the rdp connection in the HTTPS traffic as in a successfull connection? Is this some kind of fallback strategy or just a plain bug? And what could be used as advanced troubleshooting for the remote app, since it has no valuable log files and the RDS and RDGW servers are not und my control?

**EDIT (Added anonymised config file):**

```
redirectclipboard:i:1
redirectprinters:i:1
redirectcomports:i:0
redirectsmartcards:i:1
devicestoredirect:s:*
drivestoredirect:s:*
redirectdrives:i:1
session bpp:i:32
prompt for credentials on client:i:1
span monitors:i:1
use multimon:i:1
remoteapplicationmode:i:1
server port:i:3389
allow font smoothing:i:1
promptcredentialonce:i:0
videoplaybackmode:i:1
audiocapturemode:i:1
gatewayusagemethod:i:2
gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:1
gatewaycredentialssource:i:0
full address:s:INTERNAL-FQDN-SERVER-HOSTNAME.CUSTOMER.NET <!! EDITED FOR ANONYMIZE REASON
alternate shell:s:||name_of_remote_app_on_wts <!! EDITED FOR ANONYMIZE REASON
remoteapplicationprogram:s:||name_of_remote_app_on_wts <!! EDITED FOR ANONYMIZE REASON
remoteapplicationname:s:name_of_remote_app_on_wts <!! EDITED FOR ANONYMIZE REASON
remoteapplicationcmdline:s:
workspace id:s:INTERNAL-FQDN-SERVER-HOSTNAME.CUSTOMER.NET <!! EDITED FOR ANONYMIZE REASON
use redirection server name:i:1
loadbalanceinfo:s:tsv://MS Terminal Services Plugin.1.RemoteApp-EXT
alternate full address:s:INTERNAL-FQDN-SERVER-HOSTNAME.CUSTOMER.NET <!! EDITED FOR ANONYMIZE REASON
authentication level:i:2
prompt for credentials:i:0
negotiate security layer:i:1
gatewayhostname:s:external.gateway.ourcustomer.com <!! EDITED FOR ANONYMIZE REASON
signscope:s:Full Address,Alternate Full Address,Use Redirection Server Name,Server Port,GatewayUsageMethod,GatewayProfileUsageMethod,GatewayCredentialsSource,PromptCredentialOnce,Alternate Shell,RemoteApplicationProgram,RemoteApplicationMode,RemoteApplicationName,RemoteApplicationCmdLine,RedirectDrives,RedirectPrinters,RedirectCOMPorts,RedirectSmartCards,RedirectClipboard,DevicesToRedirect,DrivesToRedirect,LoadBalanceInfo
screen mode id:i:2
winposstr:s:0,3,0,0,800,600
compression:i:1
keyboardhook:i:2
connection type:i:7
networkautodetect:i:1
bandwidthautodetect:i:1
displayconnectionbar:i:1
enableworkspacereconnect:i:0
disable wallpaper:i:0
allow desktop composition:i:0
disable full window drag:i:1
disable menu anims:i:1
disable themes:i:0
disable cursor setting:i:0
bitmapcachepersistenable:i:1
audiomode:i:0
redirectposdevices:i:0
autoreconnection enabled:i:1
remoteapplicationicon:s:
shell working directory:s:
gatewaybrokeringtype:i:0
rdgiskdcproxy:i:0
kdcproxyname:s:
```

Comment: Would you mind copy and pasting the text of the RDP configuration that fails (without usernames or passwords)?

Comment: @user5870571 Added configuration to original questeion. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setting:

```
gatewayusagemethod:i:2
```

Is likely not appropriate for this service.

That corresponds to the setting "Bypass RD Gateway server for local addresses".

The third-party company should not be delivering RDP files with that setting enabled.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I will test it right away - another problem is that the third party company only creates temporary remote desktop users - I will report back when I have received some new credentials, but that sounds very promising!

Comment: Tested successfully, Thank you for pointing us in the right direction. Another thing, that I am curious about is how MSTSC determines if it will be connecting to a "local adress". From what I traced in Netmon I could see the internal server IP of the third-party company, but it is on a completely different subnet than our customer. No routes set, nothing that would imply a direct connection to the third-party subnet. The only thing is, the third-party network is hosted in a 10.X.X.X private subnet, and that cannot be the only criteria, because the rdp file works e.g. from our office... strange

Comment: Good question. I'm not certain, but I do know that the RDP client reports the local network address of the client to the RDG/Remote Desktop Session Host. This may be and usually is different from the client address that the RDG/Remote Desktop Session Host sees on its network adapter (public IP address that the client egresses from). That may be of some interest. It may be possible that the IP address of the client is within the range of the VLSM of the RDG/Remote Desktop Session Host subnet address range.